# Can SQL Server perform an update on rows with a set operation on the aggregate max or min value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I am a fairly experienced SQL Server developer but this problem has me REALLY stumped.

I have a FUNCTION.  The function is referencing a table that is something like this...

```
PERFORMANCE_ID, JUDGE_ID, JUDGING_CRITERIA, SCORE  
--------------------------------------------------  
101, 1, 'JUMP_HEIGHT', 8   
101, 1, 'DEXTERITY', 7  
101, 1, 'SYNCHRONIZATION', 6  
101, 1, 'SPEED', 9  
101, 2, 'JUMP_HEIGHT', 6   
101, 2, 'DEXTERITY', 5  
101, 2, 'SYNCHRONIZATION', 8  
101, 2, 'SPEED', 9  
101, 3, 'JUMP_HEIGHT', 9   
101, 3, 'DEXTERITY', 6  
101, 3, 'SYNCHRONIZATION', 7  
101, 3, 'SPEED', 8  
101, 4, 'JUMP_HEIGHT', 7   
101, 4, 'DEXTERITY', 6  
101, 4, 'SYNCHRONIZATION', 5  
101, 4, 'SPEED', 8
```

In this example there are 4 judges (with IDs 1, 2, 3, and 4) judging a performance (101) against 4 different criteria (JUMP_HEIGHT, DEXTERITY, SYNCHRONIZATION, SPEED).
(Please keep in mind that in my real data there are 10+ criteria and at least 6 judges.)

I want to aggregate the results in a score BY JUDGING_CRITERIA and then aggregate those into a final score by summing...something like this...

```
SELECT SUM (Avgs) FROM
(SELECT AVG(SCORE) Avgs 
  FROM PERFORMANCE_SCORES
  WHERE PERFORMANCE_ID=101
  GROUP BY JUDGING_CRITERIA) result
```

BUT... that is not quite what I want IN THAT I want to EXCLUDE from the AVG the highest and lowest values for each JUDGING_CRITERIA grouping.  That is the part that I can't figure out.  The AVG should be applied only to the MIDDLE values of the GROUPING FOR EACH JUDGING_CRITERIA.  The HI value and the LO value for JUMP_HEIGHT should not be included in the average.  The HI value and the LO value for DEXTERITY should not be included in the average.  ETC.

I know this could be accomplished with a cursor to set the hi and lo for each criteria to NULL.  But this is a FUNCTION and should be extremely fast.

I am wondering if there is a way to do this as a SET operation but still automatically exclude HI and LO from the aggregation?

Thanks for your help.  I have a feeling it can probably be done with some advanced SQL syntax but I don't know it.

One last thing.  This example is actually a simplification of the problem I am trying to solve.  I have other constraints not mentioned here for the sake of simplicity.

Seth

Comment: Rank over partition by judging criteria, then join rank to a tally table of range 2 to n-1?  The issue with this is if there are ties for first or last.  What is your drop rule if ties?

Comment: You can simply exclude high and low with a HAVING clause on score < max(score) and score > min(score) but that'll result in nothing for judging criteria without 3 or more distinct scores, and (as @user662852 says) it'll discard all scores with the lowest and highest values for that judging criteria. So please clarify if that's what you want or not.

Comment: Guys...it should only drop ONE for high and ONE for low in the case of a TIE.  So if my score for JUMPS are 7,8,9,9 it should get the average of 8 and 9.  It does not matter WHICH one gets dropped as long as one of the 9s (but only 1) gets dropped from the aggregation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: -Moved the WHERE clause to inside the CTE.
-Removed JudgeID from the partition

This would be my approach

```
;WITH Agg1 AS 
(
    SELECT   PERFORMANCE_ID
            ,JUDGE_ID
            ,JUDGING_CRITERIA
            ,SCORE
            ,MinFind    = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (   PARTITION BY     PERFORMANCE_ID
                                                                ,JUDGING_CRITERIA
                                                ORDER BY SCORE ASC  )
            ,MaxFind    = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (   PARTITION BY     PERFORMANCE_ID
                                                                ,JUDGING_CRITERIA
                                                ORDER BY SCORE DESC )
    FROM PERFORMANCE_SCORES
    WHERE PERFORMANCE_ID=101
)
SELECT AVG(Score)
FROM Agg1
WHERE MinFind > 1
AND MaxFind > 1
GROUP BY JUDGING_CRITERIA
```

Comment: Close enough. +1, but you should take out the filter on 101, add Performance_ID to the group by, and factor in the desired sum(avg(Score)) functionality, probably with another subquery. The key thing is row_number(), and (Doh!) I didn't think of tossing in two of them.

Comment: Philip, I agree that this grouping is not optimal. However, the question doesn't ask for a correction of the grouping. I was tempted to group exactly as you suggest, alas. +1 to your comment.

Comment: A slight variation would be to use COUNT(*) OVER instead of one of the ROW_NUMBERs, in which case the main query's WHERE condition would be a tiny bit more concise: `WHERE rnk NOT IN (1, cnt)` or `WHERE rnk BETWEEN 2 AND cnt-1` (assuming `rnk` is the ROW_NUMBER alias and `cnt` the COUNT one).

Comment: `COUNT(*) OVER` would also work. I'd favor an answer using the ranking functions, because whenever you teach someone the ranking functions they soon start writing much more flexible queries.